# How to start on this C interview code test?

Tags: c++

I got a really interesting question at a company, and I can't seem to find an answer at all.

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int num = 123456789;
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<111111111; i++)
    {
    res=(res+num)%1000000000;
    }
    printf("06 %09d", res);
    return 0;
    }
```

I should declare num so the output is my mobile number, 305089171.
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: So... you want res to be 305089171 while being ONLY able to change the initial num value?

Comment: You know what the desired output is. You know what the algorithm is. Run it backward.

Comment: It was a general "programming logic question".
Yes, I want the final output to be 305089171, only changing the num value.

I've been trying for hours, but can't seem to find an answer

Comment: @RawN `#include <cstdio>` not compliant C.

Comment: How to run it backward? I cant figure it out

Comment: In this case it is even sufficient to go through the algorithm forward with the example number and see what happens. Running backward: Suppose `res==305089171` at the end. What could `res+num` have been in the last loop iteration to get that? Then: What could `num` and `res` have been to get that and so on, until you see a pattern.

Comment: I meant the output is 06 305089171

Comment: @Eichhörnchen I tried that, but no luck so far..

Comment: If you really tried it then you could explain your thoughts in the question and it might be received better. If you know what `%` does then the solution here should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Good point @Eichhörnchen. IN this case I think we need to use some basic math. when you add the same number over and over again, you're multiplying. I can't remember the right word (commutative?) but A x B % C is going to be the same regardless of how you do it.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this, as far as I know,  %09d "cuts" the last 9 digits?

Comment: No. It prints a minimum of 9 digits padding with 0s if less than 9. It does nothing to the number.

Comment: @ÁdámTósaki I was talking about the `%` in `res=(res+num)%1000000000;`. `%09d` really has no bearing on this question, but you should know what `%d` does if you are taking C/C++ interview questions.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen It's hard to explain, this was kind of a "bonus question" thing, im a c# developer intern, so this is not my table at all.

% gives u the residual, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: I am quite sure that the relevant code (the loop) looks pretty much the same in C#. The printf simply prints out the number with padding to the correct length and the correct prefix. The significant part of the question is only the loop and `%` is the modulo operator (integer divison remainder), the same as in C#.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve the problem we begin with units digit.

1. We need 1 at units digit so make num  = 1.
2. Now we have res as 111111111.
3. Now we need 7 at tens digits. So we make num = (7 - 1(tens digit in step 2)) 1 = 61. (Also note that multiplying digit at tens place will only affect digts to left of it).
4. Now we have res as 777777771.
5. Now we need 1 at hundreds place. So if we make num = 461 (since 7+4 = 1)
6. and so on.

The mathematical reasoning I could think of is when you multiply a number by 111111111, digits at say tens place will only affect digits to left of it and not the digits to right of it.

Comment: I think @Treycos was using a similar approach. I do not have enough reputation to comment so I posted a new answer. Hope the explanation makes it clear.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the value you need to put in num:

```
254197461
```

I got it by adding additional numbers one by one to num, i let you check what happens yourself. 
I have no mathemacital explaination to that, but try putting numbers one by one into num and you may understand:. 
1 / 61 / 461 / 7461...

Comment: Feel free to complete it with a mathematical answer since i used the dirty way ;)

Comment: IMHO if you don't explain in detail how (and why) to obtain the result, this answer is absolutely useless. Looking at this as an interviewer, the actual number is quite irrelevant compared to the reasoning and the algorithm to obtain it.

Comment: It seems to be something particular with numbers composed of only '1'

Comment: 254197461 x 111111111  = 28244162**305089171**. Get it?

Comment: Wait how do you get a number which has the last 9 digist  305089171 and also can be /-ed by 111111111?...

Comment: @ÁdámTósaki That I will admit I'm not entirely sure of, but the solution set is fairly small. I'd brute-force it or ask a mathematician if I needed a general solution. I'm pretty sure there's some simple bit of math at play here that I don't know or don't know I know.

Comment: @ÁdámTósaki  Cryptographers do math like this all the time. Odds are good that if you ask one they'll go, "Oh! That old gag!" and explain the trick or provide an efficient solution for cracking it.